# How to retrieve body of "verify_function" Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am auditing an Oracle BD and I need to know the password policy assigned to this Database.

One way I thought to do it is retrieving the body of verify_function that is assigned to the profiles.

How can I list the body of these "verify_function"? Such as the body of `utlpwdmg.sql` and ora12c_strong_verify_function etc.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see the problem from the comments you can't find the function "ORA_COMPLEXITY_CHECK" which is an oracle standart function. The code might be obtained under

```
{ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/admin/catpvf.sql
```

And it could be that the catpvf.sql script wasn't executed against the instance you're on.

In general, here is the script to get the ddl of an object withour specifying it's type(might take longer time to execute).

```
select owner, object_name, object_type, dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name) 
from dba_objects
 where object_name = 'CFL_BITAND';
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you'd get the DDL for any object in the database -- [dbms_metadata.get_ddl](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026).  There's nothing magic about the particular function you are after. It's just another function defined in the database.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('FUNCTION','ORA_COMPLEXITY_CHECK','SYS') from dual; and it returns:

ORA-31603: object "ORA_COMPLEXITY_CHECK" of type FUNCTION not found in schema "SYS"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5805
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8344
ORA-06512: at line 1
31603. 00000 -  "object \"%s\" of type %s not found in schema \"%s\""
*Cause:    The specified object was not found in the database.
*Action:   Correct the object specification and try the call again.

Comment: So show the query and  result set that proves that you have a function named ORA_COMPLEXITY_CHECK.  Or that you have actually enabled any verify function at all.  select * from dba_profiles
where resource_name='PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';